# Spring Boot application return 403 status for all requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Hi I have created security config like in snippet below:

```java
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                   .csrf()
                   .disable()
                   .authorizeRequests()
                   .antMatchers("/panel/**")
                   .hasRole("PANEL")
                   .and()
                   .build();}

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService( PanelProperties panelProperties) {

        UserDetails panelUser = prepareUserDetails(panelProperties.getUser(), panelProperties.getPassword(), "PANEL");

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(panelUser);
    }

    private UserDetails prepareUserDetails(String username, String password, String... roles) {
        return User.withUsername(username)
                   .password(password)
                   .roles(roles)
                   .build();
    }
}
```

for every request im getting 403 FORBIDDEN http response with debug logs:

```
2022-08-01 17:51:24.914 DEBUG [app,add8f5df2fde13bb,add8f5df2fde13bb] 90089 --- [http-nio-7777-exec-9] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet:119 : "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error", parameters={}
2022-08-01 17:51:24.914 DEBUG [app,add8f5df2fde13bb,add8f5df2fde13bb] 90089 --- [http-nio-7777-exec-9] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping:522 : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2022-08-01 17:51:24.915 DEBUG [app,add8f5df2fde13bb,add8f5df2fde13bb] 90089 --- [http-nio-7777-exec-9] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor:268 : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2022-08-01 17:51:24.915 DEBUG [app,add8f5df2fde13bb,add8f5df2fde13bb] 90089 --- [http-nio-7777-exec-9]
```

When I replaced lines antMatchers and hasRole with anyRequests().permitAll() it started worked but without security

It seems like userDetailsService not works correctly. Do you have any ideas why it may not work?

update:
I have also bean:

```java
@Configuration
public class PasswordEncoderConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

And password are hashed with bCrypt correctly

update2:

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "security")
@Data
@ToString(exclude = {"panelUserPassword"})
class SecurityUsersProperties {

    @NotNull
    private String panelUser; //panel

    @NotNull
    private String panelUserPassword; //password encoded brypt
}
```

Comment: PanelProperties are properties for user with role panel, simply panel password for now, Added how does it looks like in post update

Comment: userDetailsService is a bean, so spring boot app if Im thinking good should use it in autoconfiguration

Comment: I think you must first override WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter's userDetailsService method.

Comment: Ye I was doing it before in my apps but for now WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated. https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

Comment: Ok, you're using spring security 5.x

Comment: Problem solved, all of that was my mistake cuz I forgot to enable http basic authentication and I couldnt log in, but I still dont know why it was 403 status.

Comment: Because as you can see, spring tries to redirect you to `/error` which is the default error page but you have not declared it to be permitted. Thats my guess but you have not posted your full logs so its impossible to know what happens up to the errors

Comment: It was actually all, I did not see anything more with, even with debug enabled